# How to access c# variable value in javascript function in .net MVC3?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to access a c# variable value inside a javascript function whose code is similar to this snippet below:

`@{
    var i=0;
}`

`....`

`<script type="javascript">`

`function MyObjects(e) {`

`for (j = 0; j <= @i; j++) {....}`

`</script>`

`.....`
`{
i=@i+1;}`

Comment: This is not even wrong. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: when I access i value inside javascript, I can just find its value as 0, instead of updated value.

Comment: I understand it doesn't work, but what are you *trying* to do? Why are you trying to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't "access" a C# variable from JavaScript because the C# code runs on the server side to render HTML, and the HTML including the generated JavaScript runs in the client browser.

If you want to render the value of a C# variable into the JavaScript code that runs on the client, your code

```
for (j = 0; j <= @i; j++) {....}
```

does just that.

However, if you expect

```
{ i=@i+1;}
```

to run on the client and affect the state on the server, it will not.

**Solution**

If you need to update the state of something on the server from JavaScript without posting the HTML page back to the server, you can do that with an Ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can get C#/Razor values as a string easily enough.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = parseInt("@i");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks all. I got what i want.