# how we initialize javascript var to c# var Asp.net MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to save UserName in to valC#

```
@{
var valC#;
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var UserName = $(".dir span").text();
        UserName.trim().replace("\n", "");

        alert(UserName);
    });
```

Please tell how to save value from java-script variable to a variable of C#

```
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724623/how-to-access-c-sharp-variable-value-in-javascript-function-in-net-mvc3

Answer (score 1):

If you need to push a value from client side (JavaScript) to server side (your C# code is executed on the server) you need to send it to the server in some fashion.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var UserName = $(".dir span").text();
    UserName.trim().replace("\n", "");

    $.post("@Url.Action("SaveUserName")", { username: UserName });
});
```

This will post the entered username to the Action SaveUserName on the same
controller that your current view was activated from. So on your controller
you will need the following Action

```
public ActionResult SaveUserName(string username)
{
    // This is where you would save the username on the serverside
}
```

Comment: I think you mean '@Url.Action("SaveUsername")'.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I meant. Thank you